# Can you sync a Facebook event to an events section on a website?

Tags: facebook, events

I'm currently developing an events section on a website. Users will be able to post events on this website. I was wondering if there's any way to sync a Facebook event with the form on my website.

We would specifically be looking to fill as many of the following fields as possible:

```
Country : 

Region/City : 

Venue :   

Genre :

Date :

Start/End Time : 

Name  : 

Cost :

Jpeg / Image : 

Info :
```

Anyone know of anything similar to this?

Thanks

Comment: Have you checked out the events api - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/event/ ? You can pretty much read many of the fields you are looking to fill via that api..of course in order to read private events, you need a user access token.